# Woo-commerce Reviews are not working on single product page

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, review

Woo-commerce product reviews are not working for single product page. I'm using flatsome theme.

1. I already "Enable product reviews" from woo-commerce product
   settings
2. I already allow comments from WordPress discussion settings
3. I already Enable Reviews from single product page and added some
   comments on some products. e.g: http://edsfze.xyz/elexon/product/el-1640-multi-functional-rechargeable-lamp/
4. Also Tried Woo-commerce advanced reviews plugin.

But, still no luck getting reviews or comments on products.

Here is the link of setup: http://edsfze.xyz/elexon/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That was theme issue. Contacted with their support and they resolved it.